# How to open Exchange 2010 Shared Calendar?

Tags: evolution, ms-exchange

I'm quite new to the whole Linux world, and I'm trying to migrate the whole of my pc to Linux and show that it can keep up with all of my company requirements (we are specialized on CISCO Networking, Voip and Datacenter solutions).

Unfortunately I seem to have reached a dead-end.

Aside from an actual bug on Evolution Mail in the signature bit - adding an image to sig is fine, hyperlinking over it CRASHES THE CLIENT (!)...

This could be ok if it wasn't for the fact that also opening shared exchange calendars seems to be impossible. I tried several links on google, I already managed to connect correctly to Exchange 2010, but there is no shared calendars option that I can see. I tried opening a calendar in my work mail, but it seems the only option you can get is to open your personal one.

One more thing which is really bugging me, changing the View to a personalized one (By Date-Descending) isn't retained on Evolution Mail restart (every folder will get back to the original setting, which is incomprehensible to me).

Do you guys have any amazing terminal commands that I could run to fix these issues? Up until now any even small thing I wanted to tweak already had an answer somewhere, still this seems to be absolutely impossible to resolve.

I am running on Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS with kernel 3.2.0-32-generic-pae on a Acer Travelmate 8372 (I know, poor machine, but what can I do...).

Comment: Suggestion: Consider editing out the "which is really bugging me" and "which is incomprehensible to me". They make what is an otherwise valid secondary question sound like a gripe. $0.02

Answer (score 24):

To expand upon Ubuntuser's comment that helped me along the path:

1. Set up evolution-ews and get your inbox functional. Make sure you're online, and syncing.
2. On the Mail view, right click your exchange account, select "Subscribe to folder of other EWS user."
3. Type in the name of the account you want, and choose Calendar from the dropdown.

It will silently add itself to the calendar view under your exchange account.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you very much. (I only joined this Stack Exchange Community to say thank you)

Comment: How can I subscribe to a user's secondary calendar?

Comment: One thing to add: I'm using evolution-ews 3.36.5-1. I coudn't find _"Subscribe to folder of other EWS user."_ in the **Mail View**. If anyone got the same issue:

Go to the **Calendar view** and then click on _File_ in the menu bar. There, you will find the entry  _"Subscribe to folder of other EWS user..."_

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to move it to Outlook 2k10 on a VMware Workstation vm... It beats a little the whole concept of using "free software", but as long as there is not a full implementation with exchange I reckon a full Linux solution is absolutely unmanageable (at least, not as business/enterprise users with a MS infrastructure).

Comment: works with Evolution EWS 3.10. Right click on the account, select "Subscribe to folder other EWS user" . Search for the user and select calendar. It should work!

Comment: This really doesn't answer the question...